# Displaying a Image when no contact image is available

Tags: android, contacts

I have written an app that simply shows me all the available contacts on the phone. The app is working fine. It can retrieve contact image and display_name. However, on scrolling the list, app somewhat lags. I want to know how I can remove this lag. And at the same time, I want to display an image when no contact image is available. I tried to make a boolean flag that told me whether contact image cursor was null, if it was then i make the flag (image_found) to false and then tried to set image using setImageResource, but it didn't work. Well, Then I thought that blob object may get a null when no image is there, but it dint worked too. Here is my code for mail_activity.

```
package legacy_systems.aggregatedcontactlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                              null, 
                                              null, 
                                              null, 
                                              ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");

        ArrayList<String> con_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(c!=null)
        {
            for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                con_ids.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
            }
        }



        ListView ls = getListView();

        MyAdapter ada = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, con_ids);

        ls.setAdapter(ada);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

And here is the code for MyAdapter

```
package legacy_systems.aggregatedcontactlist;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context cont;
    boolean image_found = true;
    ArrayList<String> ids;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        cont = context;
        ids = objects;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //For Contact Photo
        Bitmap photo=null;
        //Inflator Work
        LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater)cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = infl.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

        //Retreiving photo and Setting Photo
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(retrievePhoto(ids.get(position)));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listicon);
        iv.setImageBitmap(photo);

        if(!image_found)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.person);
        }

        //Retrieving ContactName
        TextView tv  =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        tv.setText(retrieveName(ids.get(position)));

        return row;
    }

    private InputStream retrievePhoto(String Id)
    {
        Uri ContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(Id));
        Uri PhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        Cursor c = cont.getContentResolver().query(PhotoUri, new String[]{Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null,null,null);

        try
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                byte[] data = c.getBlob(0);
                if(data!=null)
                {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    image_found = false;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String retrieveName(String Id)
    {
        Uri ContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(Id));
        Cursor c = cont.getContentResolver()
                        .query(ContactUri, 
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, 
                                null, 
                                null, 
                                null);
        if(c==null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                String name = c.getString(0);
                return name;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am really happy that I went this far. Please help me to continue my venture.

[EDIT]
I have implemented the suggested things, now I am not able to retreive a single contact  image. I do not know what the problem is. I have made changes only in MyAdapter.java, and I am posting the Code for it.

```
package legacy_systems.aggregatedcontactlist;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context cont;
    boolean image_found = true;
    ArrayList<String> ids;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        cont = context;
        ids = objects;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = ConvertView;
        //For Contact Photo
        Bitmap photo=null;
        //Inflator Work
        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater)cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = infl.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        }

        //Retreiving photo and Setting Photo
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listicon);


        synchronized (iv) {
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(ids.get(position)));
            PhotoLoader loader = new PhotoLoader(iv, contactUri);
            loader.execute();

        }



        //Retrieving ContactName
        TextView tv  =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        tv.setText(retrieveName(ids.get(position)));

        return row;
    }



    private String retrieveName(String Id)
    {
        Uri ContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(Id));
        Cursor c = cont.getContentResolver()
                        .query(ContactUri, 
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, 
                                null, 
                                null, 
                                null);
        if(c==null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                String name = c.getString(0);
                return name;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class PhotoLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        final WeakReference<ImageView> mView;
        final Uri mUri;

        public PhotoLoader(ImageView view, Uri uri) {

            if(view == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("View Cannot be null");
            }
            if(uri == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri cant be null");
            }
            mView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(view);
            mUri = uri;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...args){
            Bitmap bitmap;
            InputStream in = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cont.getContentResolver(), mUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            if(bitmap == null)
            {   Resources mResources = cont.getResources();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.person);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

}
```

I have not implemented Cache. When this problem is resolved, I would try to implement cache and Holder. Until then, please sort out the problem,

[Re-Edit]
This time. images are all messed up.

```
package legacy_systems.aggregatedcontactlist;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context cont;
    boolean image_found = true;
    ArrayList<String> ids;
    ImageView iv;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        cont = context;
        ids = objects;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = ConvertView;
        //For Contact Photo

        //Inflator Work

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater)cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = infl.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        }


        //Retreiving photo and Setting Photo
        iv = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listicon);


        synchronized (this) {
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(ids.get(position)));
            PhotoLoader loader = new PhotoLoader(iv, contactUri);
            loader.execute();

        }



        //Retrieving ContactName
        TextView tv  =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        tv.setText(retrieveName(ids.get(position)));

        return row;
    }



    private String retrieveName(String Id)
    {
        Uri ContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(Id));
        Cursor c = cont.getContentResolver()
                        .query(ContactUri, 
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, 
                                null, 
                                null, 
                                null);
        if(c==null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                String name = c.getString(0);
                return name;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class PhotoLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        final WeakReference<ImageView> mView;
        final Uri mUri;

        public PhotoLoader(ImageView view, Uri uri) {

            if(view == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("View Cannot be null");
            }
            if(uri == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri cant be null");
            }
            mView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(view);
            mUri = uri;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...args){
            Bitmap bitmap;
            InputStream in = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cont.getContentResolver(), mUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);


            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            if(bitmap == null)
            {   Resources mResources = cont.getResources();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.person);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                return;
            }
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To solve your problem, you might need to display image asynchronously . You can find a lot of examples online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally tackled all my problems. It occurred to me that it would be best for application to not to use a custom adapter, so, it is always good to use already provided adapters. I my case, I decided to go with SimpleCursorAdapter. And to tackle the question to display the image when no contact image is available, one simple needs to define a pre defined image as a source for contact image location in layout file. If the contact has no image, bitmap contains null, so, trick would be not to change the image when contact image is not present.

Here is my code for MyAdapter that simple extends SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
package com.example.contact;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private Cursor cursor;  
    private static int con_id_index;
    private static Drawable person;
    private Context context;
    private static LruCache<Long, Bitmap> cache;
    long con_id;
    private ArrayList<Long> id_list = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.cursor = c;        
        con_id_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        person = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person);
        this.context = context;

        final int maxMem = (int)Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024;
        final int cacheSize = maxMem/8;

        cache = new LruCache<Long, Bitmap>(cacheSize);
        id_list.clear();
    }   


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        Object tag;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        con_id = cursor.getLong(con_id_index);
        if(!id_list.contains(Long.valueOf(con_id)))
        {
            id_list.add(con_id);
        }
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, con_id);

        ImageView con_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_iamge);
        tag = con_id;
        con_image.setImageDrawable(person);
        con_image.setTag(tag);
        if(getBitmapFromCache(con_id)!=null)
        {
            con_image.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromCache(con_id));
        }
        else
        {
            ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(con_image, contactUri, con_id);
            loader.execute();
        }

    }

    class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        private ImageView mView;
        private Uri mUri;       
        private Object tag;
        private long position;

        public ImageLoader(ImageView view, Uri uri, long position) {

            if(view == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("View Cannot be null");
            }
            if(uri == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri cant be null");
            }
            mView = view;
            tag = mView.getTag();
            this.position = position;
            mUri = uri;         
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...args){
            Bitmap bitmap;

            //Load image from the Content Provider
            InputStream in = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), mUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            //If is in somewhere else, do not temper
            if(!mView.getTag().equals(tag))
                return;
            //If no image was there and do not put it to cache
            if(bitmap!= null)
            {   

                mView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                addBitmapToCache(position, bitmap);
                return;
            }
            //Otherwise, welcome to cache           
            return;
        }
    }
    /**Add image to cache*/
    private void addBitmapToCache(Long key, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if(getBitmapFromCache(key)==null)
        {
            cache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }
    /**Retrive image from cache*/
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromCache(Long key)
    {
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    public ArrayList<Long> getIDList()
    {
        return id_list;
    }

}
```

Since, loaded cursor does not contains images and content provider does not allows us to query more than one tables at a time. So, it would be best to retrieve the images in a background thread. That's where I used ASyncTask.

MyAdpter does not over rides getView(), instead it over rides bindView(), which allows to add/bind additional information to the view being inflated. Adapter makes use of memory caching and uses the contact id as a key to retrieve and store the images in cache.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Other than what Gabe Sechan said about the view being inflated every time, you should change a few things. Instead of using the content provider to get the photo use the `openContachPhotoInputStream` method in the Contacts class, which you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri%29). You should also move the opening and loading of the bitmap to a background thread using an AsyncTask. And last, try to use a `LruCache` to cache already open bitmaps for efficiency as it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). I've recently had to do something similar so I'm sharing a snippet of code to give you a hand. I use this to load the images on the background.

```
class PhotoLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    final WeakReference<ImageView> mView;
    final Uri mUri;

    PhotoLoader(ImageView view, Uri uri) {
        if (view == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("View cannot be null!");
        }

        if (uri == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri cannot be null!");
        }

        mView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(view);
        mUri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... args) {
                    // use the uri passed to the constructor
        InputStream is = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(mResolver,
                mUri);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                    // load custom resource image if contact has no photo
        if (bm == null) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources,
                    R.drawable.ic_contact);
        }

        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    // use a transition drawable for nice fade effect
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = mResources.getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);

        layers[1] = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, result);
        TransitionDrawable t = new TransitionDrawable(layers);
        t.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);

        ImageView view = mView.get();

        if(view != null) {
            view.setImageDrawable(t);
            t.startTransition(mShortAnimation);
        }
        synchronized (mPhotoCache) {
                            // store bitmap in LruCache for later use...
            mPhotoCache.put(mUri.toString(), result);
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this in my adapter:

```
synchronized (mPhotoCache) {
    Bitmap b = mPhotoCache.get(key);

    if (b != null) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
    } else {
    imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    PhotoLoader loader = new PhotoLoader(imageView, uri);
    loader.execute();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm using the contacts uri in string format as the cache key. In the adapter somewhere before checking the cache I have the following line:
`String key = uri.toString();`

Comment: I have made changes in the code but now it is not retrieving any image. I have no idea why it is happening. please. help me.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't include the `onPostExecute` method in your code and that's where your view will be updated. The `doInBackground` method gets executed on a separate thread, loading the bitmap, and the result, which is the contact photo bitmap, is sent to `onPostExecute`. Right now you are not doing anything with the bitmap. If you don't want to include the cache, just make sure you comment only the lines that have to do with it (mPhotoCache).

Comment: I again made a few amends. This time application retrives images, but they are mixed up, sometime, they are for the right person and on scrolling, some contact images change continusly then settle on one(Incorrect one). What I am doing wrong. Please. Check the re-edited code.

Comment: Your `onPostExecute` is wrong... If you look at the code I posted and follow the same steps you can fix it quite easily. First load all your bitmaps inside `doInBackground` which includes checking if the bitmap is null and loading a default one from your resources. Then, inside `onPostExecute` you get the image view you passed on the constructor using `mView.get()` since it's a weak reference (google it if you don't know what it is) and load the image there. DO NOT use `iv` which could be anything since it's running on a different thread (and do not set it as an instance variable).

Comment: @ebarrenechea what is type of `mPhotoCache` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your getView is inflating a new row every call.  It should only do that if the view passed in is null, otherwise it should override the view passed in.  That will speed up a lot of the lag

Comment: Pretty good example of two techniques to achieve this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_ConvertView

Comment: And what about displaying image when no contact image is present in the content provider.